# Send order of jQuery sortable to Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a collection of `Article` objects that have a public attribute `int priority`. This field ist used to display the articles in the intended order. However, I'd like to be able to rearrange the order of the articles in the admin area.

I included jQuery and with this Laravel/Blade snippet

```
<ul class="selectable-demo-list" id="sortable-list-basic">
    @FOREACH($articles as $article)
        <li> {{ $article->label}} </li>
    @ENDFOREACH
</ul>
```

I can produce this HTML output:

```
<ul class="selectable-demo-list" id="sortable-list-basic">
    <li> My article (ID: 1) </li>
    <li> Another article (ID: 2) </li>
    <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

I can access the respective priority via `$article->priority` and their unique IDs via `$article->id` if these elements should be included in the code.

The `<ul>` posted above is rendered correctly: All `<li>` elements are displayed as sortable jQuery elements. If I drag an item to a certain position, it stays there for the time being.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to save the new order (= update the items priorities according to the list positions).

This shouldn't be done directly. Instead, I want to use an update button. Maybe I can use a form and send an array like this to my controller:

```
$priorities = [1=>3; 2=>1; 3=>2] // ID => new priority
```

Is this possible? Or should I use a different approach? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

1. Add id with each of your li like id="id-{{ $article['id'] }}"
2. You can call an ajax request when you are changing any order using this sortable plugin like below code

   ```
    $("#sortable-list-basic").sortable({
      update: function (e, u) {
       var data = $(this).sortable('serialize');
       $.ajax({
           url: "{{ url('controller/sorting_method') }}",
           type: 'post',
           data: data,
           success: function (result) {

           },
           complete: function () {

           }
       });
     }

   });
   ```
3. Then inside your method, take your new order for each item & save it to database such as

   ```
      $ids = $request->id;

      foreach($ids as $order => $id){
       $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
       $article->order = $order;
       $article->save();
      }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but I don’t quite understand this. Does it trigger the DB Update immediately when I move an item? How do I access the new values? Are they part of the request?

Comment: add console.log(data) below var data = $(this).sortable('serialize'); then you can check what it's returning & each of your li element should have an id. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Hm. I added the ID to the `<li>` elements and also `console.log(data)` below `var data...`. However, my browser doesn't show anything in the console. Do I need to take care of csfr token issues? Is the new order stored as soon as I move an item or do I have to implement a save-button?

Comment: Yes, csrf token can be an issue. Have you checked your network tab? What is the output of your ajax call?

Comment: Thanks, but I gave up on this one. Finally, I implanted a sorting function based on Laravel only. No js.